# Как объединить значения нескольких строк таблицы?

Tags: выборка, sql

Есть таблица вида:

01:00, Параметр1, Значение
01:00, Параметр2, Значение
01:00, Параметр3, Значение
....
03:00, Параметр1, Значение
03:00, Параметр2, Значение
03:00, Параметр3, Значение  и т.д.

Можно ли запросом SQL получить такую выборку

01:00, Значение*Параметра1, Значение*Параметра2, Значение*Параметра3

...

03:00, Значение*Параметра1, Значение*Параметра2, Значение*Параметра3

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно да. Что-нибудь типа:

```
select time, sum (case when parname='Параметр1' then parval else 0 end) as par1, sum (case when parname='Параметр2' then parval else 0 end) as par2, sum (case when parname='Параметр3' then parval else 0 end) as par3 from t group by time;
```

Если есть строки с одинаковым параметром и временем -- получите сумму (можете использовать другие агрегатные функции)

Comment: Да, спасибо! Это работает.